# Why there is both "einem" und "der" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, article

I have this text from a textbook. There is a sentence I do not quite understand why is it constructed as it is.

> Na ja, ich bin mit einem der beiden zusammen, aber nicht so glücklich, weil er ja weit weg wohnt.

The text is about some girl who met 2 boys.

So my questions are -

1. Why is there **mit einem der beiden** (Wouldn't be *mit der beiden* sufficient ?)
2. What would be to best translation to english ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *der* here is the genitive plural. So *der beiden* here means "of the two"; German often uses *beiden* where English would use "two" instead of "both". So the word for word translation would be something like "I'm with one of the two, but ... ". Though I think you'd rephrase the English to say "one of them".

Comment: Many learners also struggle with the fact that *ein-* can be a pronoun.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, translated to English, you might see the difference:

1. Why is there "with one of the two" (wouldn't it be sufficient "with both")?

This translation already answers (2), I think.

Comment: If the OP was able to correctly translate the sentence into english, then he would probably not have asked the question ;)

Comment: @Tode, true, however I still wonder what he thought that his suggested version means.

Answer (score 2):

My assumption (based on assigned tags) is, that your confusion is caused by the fact, that *einem* and *der* are articles, so using two different ones looks exaggerated.

*Einem* can be the indefinite article in dative case, e. g. in the sentence:

> Einem Blinden fällt die Orientierung schwer.

In your sentence another meaning of *ein* (see [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/ein#1)) applies, the indefinite pronoun, (see section II), but one could also consider it as the inflected number (section III), similar to:

> I radle mit zwei(en) aus meiner Klasse an den See. (I make a bicycle tour to a sea with two guys from my class.)